# Input Accessory View misplaced on pressing return key

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

I'm using 
https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView

In my project on pressing return key size of textview increases but empty space appears between keyboard and inputaccessoryview. Here are the screenshots

**First time it is fine**

[image]

**But when I press return key this happens**

[image]

i tried https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALTextInputBar and https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageInputBar too but same thing is happening. Need help.

Comment: I think you must be playing with the vertical position of the textView so can you share code related to that for better help?

Comment: https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView/blob/master/InputAccessoryView/FlexibleTextView.swift this is the code i'm using for textview

Comment: hy! i am facing same issue did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: no, nothing. let me know if you find something